# Using HybridProperty to combine and format date and time columns

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a model with two columns of type `Date` and `Time`.  I would like my queries to return those columns together and formatted. I tried using a `hybrid_property` like this:

```
@hybrid_property
def mydate_and_mytime(self):
    return self.mydate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " + " self.mytime.strftime("%H:%M")
```

However, inside the property, the type of `self.mydate` and `self.mytime` is `InstrumentedAttribute` which does not have the `strftime` method, and it raises an error.

How can I make the following query work?

```
session.query(MyModel.mydate, MyModel.mytime, MyModel.mydate_and_mytime)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except for simple expressions, a hybrid property requires a getter and an expression part.  Take advantage of built-in functions to combine dates and times, then format.

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property


@hybrid_property
def mydate_and_mytime(self):
    combine = datetime.combine(self.mydate, self.mytime)
    return combine.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

@mydate_and_mytime.expression
def mydate_and_mytime(cls):
    # return a sqlalchemy expression based on the columns
    # uses MySQL timestamp and date_format functions
    combine = db.func.timestamp(cls.mydate, cls.mytime)
    return db.func.date_format(combine, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
```

In my opinion, the formatting should be left to something outside the property in order to compare actual datetimes, but that's your call.